# Question about migration

Tags: support, migration

[This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/567108/pre-algebra-text-book-or-online) was migrated from mathoverflow, which is great, but I noticed the OP seems to have become "none none" in the process? Is this a problem with the migration process? Has the OP been notified of the migration and will they be able to track answers, since they seem not to be in the system any more?

Comment: The user on the MO original appears to be »none none« as well.

Comment: @ArthurFischer: thanks for the info. Do you know what that signifies?

Comment: I think it signifies that the [user](http://mathoverflow.net/users/42798/none-none) chose "none none" as his or her display name on SE network, both on MathOverflow and StackOverflow.

Comment: @user103254: Okay, but the image associated with is is the image associated with deleted accounts.

Comment: The username is in unclickable grey and has placeholder avatar because the user does not have a Math.SE account. This is often the case for migrated questions; there is nothing unusual here.  If/when the user adds Math.SE to the bundle of SE network accounts, the name will be displayed normally.

Comment: @user103254: Okay, thanks. I mainly wanted to know if it was worth investing the time to answer if the OP never even knows to check the migrated question.

Comment: The OP can still see the question on MO, with [migrated] at the end of title; clicking the title will send the OP here. Also, the OP's user page lists the question as well. I do not know if the answers given on Math.SE will result in notifications for OP before Math.SE account is created... they might. In any event, if the OP never sees the answer(s) given on Math.SE, the reason will be their lack of interest, not lack of opportunity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned above, »none none« appears to be the chosen name of this user.  The fact that the math.SE account is "blank" and unclickable only means that a math.SE account has not been set up.  As »none none« appears to be a registered user on MO, it still leaves open the possibility of setting up a math.SE account with the same OpenID information, which would then connect the two accounts.

When a question is migrated, the user who asked it is [notified](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/29344/214632) of this via the SE-network messaging system.  So if/when »none none« decides to log in to MO again, they should see this message, come to math.SE and ideally set up an associated math.SE account.