# Do users receive notifications when their question is migrated?

Tags: support, migration, notifications

The user is not registered in math.stack but they have a question on math.stack.

Are they still notified by some actions on their post?

Comment: similar https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11661/question-about-migration?rq=1

Comment: Some notification is mentioned here: [Remind new users to create/associate accounts if a question has been migrated to a site on which the user does not have an account](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/148761). (Although that post is from 2012, some thing might have changed since then.)

Comment: I found this related feature request: [Notifications on migrated question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/73687).

Comment: @MartinSleziak thank you for the links